# can I download others(public) github directory into my local git directory using command line?

Tags: git, github

I want to download download certain directory from others github repository into my local git directory. Is that possible?

Comment: You can copy any project from github using `git clone`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+directory